# My Firefox extension not loading on browser

Tags: php, firefox, firefox-addon

My Firefox extension not loading on browser.

I uploaded it my server but when i clicking that link , it's not loading my browser. I have been seen just content codes.

How can i change content type as application/x-xpinstall ?

http://www.alisverisbook.com/zamantunelikaldirma/install.php?type=firefox

images:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output a `Content-type` header in "install.php" prior to reading the file contents to the browser.

```
header("Content-type: application/x-xpinstall");
```